# Display Custom Field on Email in Wordpress/Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I need to display the custom field that I added via plugin (woocommerce edit checkout fields) I need to display the field data which is a date on the email that would be sent to the customer. here is my code on the email.php (which is found on the event-tickets-plus plugin)

```
<!--Date-->
   <td class="ticket-details new-row new-left-row" valign="top" align="left" 
    width="120" style="background-color: #e1e9f6; padding: 0; width:120px; 
    margin:0 !important; text-align:center; border: 1px solid #fff;">

   <h6 style="background-color:#3b89c9; color:#fff !important; margin:0 0 
    10px 0; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
    text-transform:uppercase; font-size:14px; font-weight:700 !important;"> 
    Ticket Date 
   </h6>

   <span style="background-color: #e1e9f6; color:#0a0a0e !important; font-
     family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font 
     size:15px;">

      <?php do_action('show_date_here');?></span>

</td>
```

and here is my code on functions.php

```
  <?php

       add_action('show_date_here','get_date', 10,1);

       function get_date($order){
         $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

         $order_data = $order->get_data(); // The Order data

         $order_id = $order->get_id();

         $order_date_use = $order_data['ticket_date'];

         echo $order_date_use;

       }

   ?>
```

I hope you could help me with this.

Comment: You need to edit your code to display properly.

Comment: can you suggest a way to do it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with both technologies enough to give a working answer. I just wanted to let you know the SO community really need the code to be in proper order and readable so they can give you a proper answer.